# MySQL datatypes vs JDBC types

Tags: mysql, jdbc

How to find relationship between MySQL datatypes and JDBC types? For example, MySQL TEXT type corresponds to JDBC LONGVARCHAR. Where can we find any official documentation?

Comment: Have you looked at the [MySQL Connector/J documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference.html)? Specifically, [6.5 Java, JDBC, and MySQL Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)?

Comment: Sure, that page only says relationships between Mysql Types And Java Types. But on information about Mysql Types And JDBC Types

Comment: Combined with the definitions in appendix B of the JDBC specification, you should be able to derive it though. Also, you can use `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType` or the `DATA_TYPE` column of `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns` to get the JDBC type of a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

```
MysqlDefs.java

// Maps the given MySQL type to the correct JDBC type.

static int mysqlToJavaType(String mysqlType) {
    if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("BIT")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_BIT);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("TINYINT")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_TINY);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("SMALLINT")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_SHORT);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("MEDIUMINT")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_INT24);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("INT") || mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("INTEGER")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_LONG);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("BIGINT")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_LONGLONG);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("INT24")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_INT24);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("REAL")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_DOUBLE);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("FLOAT")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("DECIMAL")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_DECIMAL);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("NUMERIC")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_DECIMAL);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("DOUBLE")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_DOUBLE);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("CHAR")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_STRING);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("VARCHAR")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_VAR_STRING);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("DATE")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_DATE);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("TIME")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_TIME);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("YEAR")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_YEAR);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("TIMESTAMP")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_TIMESTAMP);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("DATETIME")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_DATETIME);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("TINYBLOB")) {
        return java.sql.Types.BINARY;
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("BLOB")) {
        return java.sql.Types.LONGVARBINARY;
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("MEDIUMBLOB")) {
        return java.sql.Types.LONGVARBINARY;
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("LONGBLOB")) {
        return java.sql.Types.LONGVARBINARY;
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("TINYTEXT")) {
        return java.sql.Types.VARCHAR;
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("TEXT")) {
        return java.sql.Types.LONGVARCHAR;
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("MEDIUMTEXT")) {
        return java.sql.Types.LONGVARCHAR;
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("LONGTEXT")) {
        return java.sql.Types.LONGVARCHAR;
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("ENUM")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_ENUM);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("SET")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_SET);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("GEOMETRY")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_GEOMETRY);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("BINARY")) {
        return Types.BINARY; // no concrete type on the wire
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("VARBINARY")) {
        return Types.VARBINARY; // no concrete type on the wire
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("BIT")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_BIT);
    } else if (mysqlType.equalsIgnoreCase("JSON")) {
        return mysqlToJavaType(FIELD_TYPE_JSON);
    }

    // Punt
    return java.sql.Types.OTHER;
}
```